# Accept Rate Percentage

Tags: support, user-interface, accept-rate, information-display

Is there a way to see your % Accept Rate? And what factors contribute to it?

I see it below people when they post questions and such. I was wondering where you observe yours or how this comes to be. I could not find this in the F.A.Q. I found a question similar to this but did not provide any answers.

Comment: Highly likely to be a dupe - but I can't find it right now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your accept rate will show up when you have enough questions that the criteria listed [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/).

- Questions must not be community wiki.
- Questions must not be closed.
- Questions must be more than 3 days old.
- Questions must have at least 1 answer.
- There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.

Comment: sorry to put this question here but i have accepted all answers to my questions and the acceptance rate never goes up( grayed out). Right now about 5/6 questions may be unanswered

Comment: @Deeptechtons, you only have a 79% accept rate. If you hover over the accept rate it will show that you've only accepted answers on 180 of 228 answered questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can see your own accept rate (if one exists, subject to what Brandon said) by simply clicking on one of your own questions. I'm not sure where else it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

I just eyeball the list of my questions to see my acceptance rate. But then again, all my questions fit on one screen.